# phpMyAdmin import failed "undefined"

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, docker, phpmyadmin

I tried to import a .sql file from a Docker Container phpMyAdmin setup. I received a failed "undefined" message. Below are screens of the process.

Note: I have connected to an AWS RDS Remotely. All seems to be working fine. The database is connected and I can log in just fine from the phpMyAdmin web link.

[image]

[AWS looks like it has no connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glGKX.png)

Comment: How big is your .sql file?

Comment: the file size is : 44,727,761 bytes (44.7 MB on disk). I noticed it was big so I followed a tutorial to edit the php.ini file to allow bigger sizes

Comment: So did that fix it?

Comment: added : nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
--ADD LINE-- 
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf .   That seems to be working now. Still seeing 0 connections on RDS. But during the import I saw 1 connection

Answer (score 0):

Please empty your browser cache and retry to see if the red "undefined" box still appears. It is related to the "error reporting" feature.

You should try clearing your browser cache and/or forcing it to fully reload the phpMyAdmin application.

Comment: this did not fix the issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dragging and dropping it into the PHPMyAdmin window, switch to the Import tab and upload the SQL file from the form. This will give you the reason why it does getting failed.

In my case, the database was too large to upload, so I adjusted `post_max_size` from the php.ini file, and it worked.